# Is it possible to add a different template to content type, after the content type has been used in a library?

Tags: document-library, content-type, template, content-type-hub

My client has asked whether it's possible for them to add templates to a content type after the system has gone live.  I'm wondering if any issues arise once a content type default template has been used for a period in a library, and then a completely different template is then used.

I'm using a content type hub for this EDRMS, this may complicate things further!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't have any issues by updating the template. Just make the change in your content type hub and re-publish the content types.

Documents that were created with the old template will not be updated to target the new template though. If that has to happen, they need to be updated manually.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, that's really helpful. I won't need to update the old documents.